# how can I set the location of jtextarea

Tags: java

How can I set the location of JtextArea?
[image]

I used setLocation method and setBounds but nothing worked

```
jTextArea3.setColumns(25);
   jTextArea3.setRows(30);
    jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTextArea3);
   jTextArea3.setText(s);
 jTextArea3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
```

Comment: What layout manager are you using? The code you have doesn't show this. Or are you trying to set the size of the `JTextArea` as per your image?

Comment: Where these codes are called from which method? Can you show the rest of this code?